# IBM HTTP SSL certificate not found issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

I have a dev environment with `IBM Websphere Liberty 8.5.5`; in front of this application server there is an `IBM HTTP Server` (External CA SSL certificate configured for IBM HTTP).
I'm able to access the IBM HTTP from internet but with `/mfpconsole` it throws an exception (see below).

```
[11/28/16 21:02:44:464 SGT] 00000024 com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy                    E FWLSE3301E: Problem with SSL certificates. Possible fixes: Put the application server's certificate into the truststore. Or define the JNDI property mfp.admin.ui.cors.strictssl to false (not in production environments).
[11/28/16 21:02:44:464 SGT] 00000024 com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy                    E Exception java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target while redirecting request to :443/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true
[11/28/16 21:02:49:759 SGT] 000000c9 com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager                       E CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN CN= was sent from the target host.  The signer might need to be added to local trust store .p12, located in SSL configuration alias defaultSSLConfig.  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[11/28/16 21:02:49:759 SGT] 000000c9 com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy                    E Received status 500 for GET https://url:443/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Provide your server.xml and any setup steps you have followed - per the error, it cannot find the certificate...

Comment: You have to put that external CA that is configured for your IHS to the Liberty truststore.

Comment: I added the  CA cert in Liberty truststore and it resolved the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the CA cert in Liberty truststore and it resolved the issue.Thanks